# Pushing address to another contract's array returns TypeError: Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in function

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, remix

Contract User.sol has a function `requestValidation` which interacts with another contract. Its purpose is to push the address of the User.sol's contract owner into array `pendingRequests`, stored at the other contract (TrustEntity.sol).

Contract User.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
import "browser/TrustEntity.sol";

contract User {
    // State variables
    // The contract address for the TrustEntity
    TrustEntity trustEntity;
    address owner = msg.sender;
    bool verified = false;
    uint creationTime = now;
    uint level = 0;

    // Set trustEntity's deployed contract address
    function User(address _trustEntity) {
        trustEntity = TrustEntity(_trustEntity);
    }

    function requestValidation() {
        trustEntity.pendingRequests.push(owner);
    }
}
```

Contract TrustEntity.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
import "browser/User.sol";

contract TrustEntity {
    address owner;
    address registry;
    address[] public pendingRequests;

    function verifyUsers() {
        /*
        Whenever a user requests verification, his
        address should be pushed to the pendingRequests
        array, so it can then be fetched to verify or
        reject
        */
    }   
}
```

Remix gives me the following error message:

```
browser/User.sol:19:6: TypeError: Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in function (uint256) constant external returns (address)
        trustEntity.pendingRequests.push(owner);
        ^------------------------------^
```

I've tried to push into an array stored in the contract, which works. Like so

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
import "browser/TrustEntity.sol";

contract User {
    // State variables
    // The contract address for the TrustEntity
    TrustEntity trustEntity;
    address owner = msg.sender;
    bool verified = false;
    uint creationTime = now;
    uint level = 0;
    address[] public pendingRequests;

    // Set trustEntity's deployed contract address
    function User(address _trustEntity) {
        trustEntity = TrustEntity(_trustEntity);
    }

    function requestValidation() {
        pendingRequests.push(owner);
    }
}
```

so I don't understand why it wouldn't work for another contract. Is it related to having ETH to pay for a transaction, since it's a state-altering function?

Comment: I can't push into an array stored in the contract in 0.6.0 as you were able to do in ^0.4.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contracts do not get write access into each others' state. The `public` modifier only means that the value is readable. Presuming that you are the developer of TrustEntity, I can suggest a couple options:

1. Remove the User contract entirely, storing all information about the users in the TrustEntity contract.
2. Write a "setter" in TrustEntity, like `TrustEntity.pushPending(address)` (with the appropriate account controls to prevent global write access)

In my opinion, the first is the more standard usage, based on your apparent goal. For example, token contracts typically store all the information about the owners of the token centrally, rather than add separate contracts for each user.

Option two adds a lot of gas cost and blockchain bloat, and adds more surface area for security errors.

Comment: That worked, cheers! I went for option 2 since I need a lot of other functionality in the User contract and I'd like to keep those 2 separate. Also, it's a toy app so it'll work for now.