# can't call function in one contract from another contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, contract-deployment

I'm trying to call a function in one contract from another contract with the following simple example:

Untitled.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract helloworld {
function returnint() returns (uint) {
return 15;
}
}
```

And the second contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

import "./Untitled.sol";

contract pullother {

function callFunctionInContractOne (address _address) returns (uint) {
    helloworld contractOne = helloworld(_address);
    contractOne.returnint();
}
}
```

When calling `callFunctionInContractOne()` in the second contract, the address of the deployed `Untitled.sol` is given as a parameter, then the `returnint()` function in the first contract is called (which should return 15). When I try this in the remix editor I get the following returned instead:

[image]

I am copying from [calling simple function from another contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15754/calling-simple-function-from-another-contract) but getting a different result. I've also tried running a function on one contract from another on a private blockchain in a similar way but am unsuccessful.

Adding a return value I get the same thing:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually sent a TX that call that method of the first smart contract, that called the function of the second smart contract. The thing is you are on a *real* blockchain - it seems Ropsten to me - and not in the memory of your computer, so you cannot retrieve values from a contract like that. What remix is returning to you is the transaction receipt after the block is mint.

If you want a ÐApp to be able to retrieve values directly from a contract, create functions with `constant returns`. And please note soon this constant will be split in [`view`](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html?#view-functions) and [`pure`](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html?#pure-functions).

Answer (score 0):

You should add a return value for `callFunctionInContractOne` function, as follows:

```
contract pullother {

    function callFunctionInContractOne (address _address) returns (uint) {
        helloworld contractOne = helloworld(_address);
        return contractOne.returnint();
    }

}
```

Testing that everything is ok. The result is :

[image]

Hope it helps~

Comment: I still seem to run into the same thing

Comment: add `constant` for `callFunctionInContractOne` function, try it.  `function callFunctionInContractOne (address _address)  constant returns (uint) {
        helloworld contractOne = helloworld(_address);
        return contractOne.returnint();
    }`